# Pyspark Ipython notebook add dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am running Pyspark and with ipython notebook and I am trying to add a jar file to the spark env. 
I tried Doing the sc.addjar to add the jar but that dint work. Any other suggestions?
I know you can do spark-submit --jars , but I am doing spark submit 
I also tried env variable SPARK_CLASS_PATH and placed the jar in that folder and restarted the ipython/spark , it picked it up as a jar but dint do anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?